# How can I assign one field's value to another field based on a third field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have three fields and if column three equals a certain value, I want to get the value of column 2.  Can I do this in a `SELECT`, and would I use an `IF` or `CASE` statement?

Comment: What do you want to do if column three *doesn't* equal a certain value?

Comment: You should really post example data, expected output, and your query so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CASE` statement would be the easiest way to do this.  The following SQL compares two columns.  You can alter this to use `WHEN Col2 = 'xxxx' THEN xxxx'`.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, CASE
                   WHEN Col2 = Col1 THEN 'True'
                   ELSE 'False'
                   END AS 'Columns Match'
  FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this leads you in the right direction

```
Select 
    Case 
       when columnthree = 'VALUE' 
          then column2 
          else 'do something' 
    end as [column name]
from 
    table name
```

Also you might want to do some conversion if the datatypes for both columns are different

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE` clause within a `SELECT` statement - `IF` won't work this way in SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Alpha, Beta, Gamma,
  case
    when Alpha > 2 * Beta then Gamma
    when Beta = Gamma then Alpha + 3
    when Gamma = 2 then 13
    else 42
    end as 'Omega'
  from Alphabet
```

First match wins.

CASE returns a value, so it may be helpful in various circumstances:

```
delete ... where case when Id > Limit then 1 else 0 end = 1
update ... set ShoeSize = case when Wide = 1 then ShoeSize + 1 else ShoeSize end, ...
```